# Memory error implementing CLLocationManagerDelegate in a separate class

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I try to move `CLLocationManagerDelegate` implementation to a separate class (file) in order not to clutter `ViewController` code but get memory error every time `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc)`
What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my implementation:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = LocationManagerDelegate()
        // >=iOS8
        if (locationManager.respondsToSelector(Selector("requestWhenInUseAuthorization"))) {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

}

class LocationManagerDelegate: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        // …
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        // …
    }

}
```

Comment: Pablo is right, you're being ARC'd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegates normally are weak so there is no object retaining your delegate and that's the cause of your Bad memory access error.

You should do something similar to this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

//instantiate and hold a strong reference to the Core Location Manager Delegate
//Normally you don't need this because the delegate is self

let locationManagerDelegate = LocationManagerDelegate() 


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self.locationManagerDelegate
    // >=iOS8
    if (locationManager.respondsToSelector(Selector("requestWhenInUseAuthorization"))) {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    } else {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

}

class LocationManagerDelegate: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    // …
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    // …
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Also does it make sense to start updating location in `viewWillAppear` method?

Comment: Yes, I think so if you always want to show the user location that shoulp prompt for the permissions as soon as possible. if you don't have still permission the delegate should start updating the location after is granted in iOS 8 so you need to start it in didChangeAuthorizationStatus